# Outlook mail body is blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following to send an email, with a range of cells from my Excel sheet.

The email is sent with the correct Subject and CC.

There is data in that cell range (A:B) but I cannot get anything in the body. It stays blank.

```
Sub SendEmail()

SendEmail Macro

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = Sheets("Test1").Range("F2").Value
    .CC = Sheets("Test1").Range("F3").Value
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Sheets("Test1").Range("E1").Text
    .Body = Sheets("Test1").Range("A:B")
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you mean the subject stays blank, or the body?

Comment: OK. Do you want to put the range into the body? Since you are using Ron de Bruin's code, why not use his [RangeToHTML](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mail/folder3/mail4.htm) code, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error trapping you have is hiding the error: `13 - Type Mismatch`

you will have to construct the `.Body` by looping through the values

Here's the code to loop through:

```
Dim I As Long
Dim LastRowColA As Long
Dim BodyString As String

BodyString = ""
LastRowColA = Sheets("Test1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
For I = 1 To LastRowColA
    BodyString = BodyString & Sheets("Test1").Range("A" & I).Value & vbTab & Sheets("Test1").Range("B" & I).Value & vbCrLf
Next I
.Body = BodyString ' instead of = Sheets("Test1").Range("A:B")
```

Comment: last row of column A: `LastRowColA = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row`, then loop though: `BodyString=BodyString & Range("A" & Loop).value & vbTab & Range("B" & Loop).value & vbCrLf`

Comment: Sorry man I can't get it to work in my code, I think it is just formatting. Do I need to put the LastRowColA = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row, Then the rest?

Comment: I am changing this a little. How would I add a column C from excel? I tried Sheets("Borrow Rates").Range("C" & I).Value & vbCrLf but it doesn't format it right

Comment: `vbTab` separates the columns, `vbCrLf` tells it to make a new line.

Comment: Geez, I thouhght it was the opposite. Thanks

Comment: BodyString = BodyString & Sheets("Borrow Rates").Range("A" & I).Value & vbTab & Sheets("Borrow Rates").Range("B" & I).Value & vbCrLf & Sheets("Borrow Rates").Range("C" & I).Value & vbTab
    I still some strange formating? I know I am making a stupid error, I just can't see it

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
Sheets("Test1").Range("E1").Text
```

to

```
Sheets("Test1").Range("E1").Value
```